# MInimal time to compute the minimal value

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

I was asked such question, what is the minimal time needed to compute the minimal value of an unsorted array of 32 integers, given that you have 8 cores and each comparison takes 1 minute. My solution is 6 minutes, assuming that each core operates independently. Divide the array into 8 portions, each has 4 integers, 8 cores concurrently compute the local min of each portion, takes 3 minutes, (3 comparisons in each portion). Then 4 cores to compute the local min of those 8 local mins, 1 minute. Then 2 cores to compute the 4 local mins, 1 minute, then 1 core to compute the global min among the remaining 2 mins, 1 minute. Therefore, the total amount is 6 minutes. However, it didn't seem to be the answer that the interviewer was looking for. So what do you guys think about it? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If* you assume that the program is CPU-bound, which is fairly ridiculous, but seems to be where you were going with your analysis, then you need to decide how to divide the work to gain something by multithreading.

8 pieces of 4 integers each seems arbitrary. Interviewers usually like to see a thought process. Being mathematically general, let us compute total orderings over subsets of the problem. How hard is it to compute a total ordering, and what is the payoff?

Total ordering of N items, picking arbitrarily when two items are equal, requires N*(N-1)/2 comparisons and eliminates (N-1) items. Let's make a table.

- N = 2: 1 comparison, 1 elimination.
- N = 3: 3 comparisons, 2 eliminations.
- N = 4: 6 comparisons, 3 eliminations.

Clearly it's most efficient to work with pairs (N = 2), but the other operations are useful if resources would otherwise be idle.

- Minute 1-3: Eliminate 24 candidates using operations with N = 2, 8 at a time.
- Minute 4: Now there are 8 candidates. Keeping N = 2 would leave 4 cores idle. Setting N = 3 uses 2 more cores per operation and yields 1 more elimination. So do two operations with N = 3 and one with N = 2, eliminating 2+2+1 = 5 candidates. Or, use 6 cores with N = 4 and two with N = 1 to eliminate 3+1+1 = 5. The result is the same.
- Minute 5: Only 3 candidates remain, so set N = 3 for the last round.

If you keep the CPUs busy, it takes 5 minutes using a mix of two higher-level abstractions. More energy is spent because this isn't the most efficient way to solve the problem, but it is faster.

Comment: I guess this should be the answer the interviewer wanted. Considering memory and I/O is quite ridiculous in this case, I believe.

Comment: @justhalf Living in the real world is *never* ridiculous. Especially in a job interview.

Comment: Anyway, as you said, the interviewer wants the thought process. So you can try to ask first "should I consider the integer as being too big in the cache that multiprocessing actually doesn't matter?". Depending on the interviewer, he might consider you as being too picky, or, if that is was really the intention of the interviewer, it's done. I'd say that this one is a really nasty question. I would probably reconsider working there, haha. I believe this answer is more appropriate to be answered first, then we can later add the memory consideration.

Comment: @justhalf Exactly. A job interview goes both ways. If the interviewer acted like I was crazy for asking about I/O, I would probably try to get a handle on whether he was a bad apple, or just decide not to work there. There is literally no point on working on multithreading without considering I/O so it's a core competency.

Comment: Agree. Nevertheless, I'll still downvote your first answer and upvote this one. =D

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Wait, in minute 4, how do you select 3 candidate in 1 minute, since filtering N = 3 candidates requires 2 comparisons on 1 core, which takes 2 minutes. Say question for the last step where N = 3 as well.

Comment: @CongHui: I was mistaken -- you can still determine the minimum element using multiple comparisons in the last step, provided you can compute logical expressions involving the results of comparisons in negligible time.  (E.g. if the last step involves comparing x1 to x2 on CPU 1, x2 to x3 on CPU 2 and x1 to x3 on CPU 3, then the answer triple "> < <" implies that x2 in CPU 2 is the minimum.)  My analysis would only apply if the operation that takes 1 minute is `min(x, y)` (and equality testing also takes 1 minute), not "is x less than y?".

Comment: @j_random_hacker I didn't think about using those inequalities to imply the winner at all. Basically out of each comparisons, the only output is the smaller one of the two. If the inequality is involved, it'd have been a tricky question.

Comment: @CongHui The table in this answer provides the costs for determining the least among N numbers in just one unit of time. Confusion over computational cost of Boolean values (which are certainly one bit) vs "integers" (which must run to gigabytes to justify the given timescale) is exactly why you shouldn't allow questions to take you into wacky fantasy-land in the first place.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I DON'T GET `N = 3: 3 comparisons, 2 eliminations.` don't a machiene just 2 comparisons ? `if(a>b) max1 = a , else b `.  now `if( max1>c) finalmax = max1 else c` .

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that comparing two "integers" is a black box that takes 1 minute to complete, but we can cache those comparisons and only do any particular comparison once.

There's not much you can do until you're down to 8 candidates (3 minutes).  But you don't want to leave cores sitting idle if you can help it.  Let's say that the candidates are numbered 1 through 8.  Then in minutes 4 you can compare:
1v2 3v4 5v6 7v8 AND 1v5 2v6 3v7 4v8
If we're lucky, this eliminates 6 candidates, and we can use minute 5 to to pick the winner.

If we're not lucky, this leaves 4 candidares (for example, 1, 3, 6, and 8), and that step didn't gain us anything over the original approach.  In minute 5, we need to throw everything at it (to beat the original approach).  But there are 8 cores, and C(4,2)=6 possible pairings.  So we can make every possible comparison (and leave 2 cores idle), and get our winner in 5 minutes.

Comment: Code for the worst case. If the extra comparisons in minute 4 may do nothing extra, those cores might as well go idle. But you can still finish in 5 minutes by doing all 6 possible comparisons on the remaining 4 candidates in minute 5. In fact that strategy is just as fast as my answer and slightly more efficient, using one less core-minute of energy (4 less in minute 4 and 3 more in minute 5).

Answer (score -2):

Those are really big integers, too big to fit into CPU cache, so multithreading doesn't really help you — this problem is I/O bound. (I suppose it depends on the specifics of the I/O bottleneck, but let's not pick nits.)

Since you need exactly N-1 comparisons, the answer is 31.

Comment: could you elaborate on this? why is it too big to fit into CPU cache? Thanks

Comment: @CongHui Because a minute is a long time. Any computer with an 8-core CPU can process many gigabytes of data per core in a minute, unless constrained by I/O, but there is no way to have a gigabyte of cache. If the cores are on different chips (or even many chips per core) the machine could be older, but usually "cores" refers to units that are not complete CPUs.

Comment: I was assuming that "integer" really meant "some object that is irrelevant to the problem".

Comment: @Teepeemm Agreed, so what?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Please forgive my ignorance about hardware, but even if the "integer" is too big to be fit into cache, but we are choked by the I/O, it still doesn't restrain us from using multiple independent cores at a time. Why does it have to be in serial? Thanks

Comment: @CongHui Multiple cores won't process data faster if they can't receive it in the first place. This is the first thing you should know about multithreading. It's pointless to attempt it if the problem is not amenable.

Comment: @Teepeemm In fact, the "compare integers" part does tell us that only a trivial amount of computational work is being done per byte of data.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It guess the question was intended to test my knowledge on hardware. I didn't think about what you said at all. :(